# Create new column based on a keyword match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match

Suppose I have this DF:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'keyword': ['Rayban', 'Rayban lens', 'Sunglasses RayBan', 'Sunglasses'],'Volume':[50,100,150,200]})`

```
             keyword  Volume
0             Rayban      50
1        Rayban lens     100
2  Sunglasses RayBan     150
3         Sunglasses     200
```

I need to create a new column "Brand" based on a keyword match. If the row on the column Keyword contains the string "Rayban", I need a that the row in the "Brand" column gets the value "Brand".

How could I do this ?

Based on the above example, I would need this output :

```
             keyword  Volume  Brand
0             Rayban      50  brand
1        Rayban lens     100  brand
2  Sunglasses RayBan     150  brand
3         Sunglasses     200  non-brand
```

I'm a beginner so let me know if something is not clear. Thank you for your help !

Comment: You've gotten a working answer to this question. Since there's only two values for the `Brand` column (indicating that something is or is not true), a better data model might be to use booleans rather than strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `str.contains()`:

```
df['Brand']='non-brand'
df.loc[df['keyword'].str.contains('Rayban',case=False),'Brand']='brand'
```

OR

```
import numpy as np

df['Brand']=np.where(df['keyword'].str.contains('Rayban',case=False),'brand','non-brand')
```

output of df:

```
    keyword         Volume      Brand
0   Rayban              50      brand
1   Rayban lens         100     brand
2   Sunglasses RayBan   150     brand
3   Sunglasses          200     non-brand
```

Comment: @LuchoSEO if it solves your query then you can try considering [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.) this answer to indicate other that the issue is solved(click on the tick to make it green).....thanks **:)**

Comment: @LuchoSEO pls see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.